# What's the correct approach for re-building a npm package within my own project?

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

**Presentation:**

I built an admin template (css + js) and I uploaded it to npm. The package contains the compiled css/js files in the "dist" folder, and the scss files in the "build" folder. The package has several dependencies which are listed as `devDependencies` in the `package.json`:

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
  "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
  "laravel-mix": "^4.0.13",
  ...
}
```

There are no `dependencies`, which I assume is correct because I directly use the compiled css/js (the js is just jQuery code).

There's an `admin.scss` file which has all the *imports*:

```css
@import 'abstracts/variables';

@import
  '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css',
  '~easymde/dist/easymde.min.css',
  '~flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css',
  '~jasny-bootstrap/dist/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css',
  '~selectizebootstrap/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap4.css';

@import
  'components/alerts',
  'components/cards';
```

I'm using the admin package in a PHP project (Laravel). The admin package is included in the `devDependencies` of my PHP project. The `admin.css` file is included in the `php.scss` file:

```
@import '../../node_modules/admin-template/dist/css/admin.css';
```

**The problem:**

I need to change some variables of the `admin.scss` file. So, instead of include the compiled `css` I need to include the `scss`:

```
@import '../../node_modules/admin-template/build/scss/admin';
```

If I do that, I get errors because the admin template `devDependencies` are not installed in my `node_modules`.

If do a `npm install` within the admin template folder, a `node_modules` folder is created and all the dependencies are installed inside that folder.
But the errors doens't go away, I think is because of the `tilde` used in the imports of the scss file: `@import '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'`. It's looking for the files in the root folder (not within the package).

**What should I do?**

- Add all the admin template `devDependencies` as `devDependencies` of my PHP project? Doesn't seems right.
- List the admin template `devDependencies` as `dependencies`, so when I install the package, all the dependencies get installed too? Doesn't seems right either, those are `devDependencies`.
- Remove the `tilde ~` off all the `@imports` in the `admin.scss` file? So if I need to include directly the scss I need to do an `npm install` within the package. And if I already have some of that packages installed in my `node_modules`, they'll be twice.
- Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, also put them into "optionalDependencies" field of `admin-template/package.json`.

This way, when you:

```
cd php-project
npm install admin-template 
# or simply `npm install` if it's already in "dependencies"
```

"optionalDependencies" of `admin-template`, like `datatables.net-bs4` will be installed into top-level `node_modules` folder. Plus, "optionalDependencies", the semantic seems pretty damn right to me.

---

Now if you really care about the install footprint for users who only use `.css` in your package, then unfortunately, no easy way to do it.

You inevitably require users of `.scss` to do some extra work. You either provide a guide for them on how to do it manually, or you can provide a script to automate that.

One possible solution is you also provide a bin file.

```
admin-template/bin/admin-template-enable-sass.js # or .sh if you prefer

// package.json
{
  "bin": "bin/admin-template-enable-sass.js"
}
```

This way, when user `npm install admin-template`, that bin file is symlinked to top-level `node_module/.bin`, making it runnable with `npx` cli command.

Now your `.scss` advance user can simply type:

```
npx admin-template-enable-sass
```

to let your script take care things for them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. So far I'll probably go with `optionalDependencies`, didn't know that exists. I'm more concerned that the package.json of my php-project it's clear about his dependencies. Is there any way to specify (in the package.json) that I need to install the `devDependencies` of a `devDependency`?

Comment: @azeós AFAIK no such way.